# Can't log into Stack Overflow with Yahoo?

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

When I try to log in with my Yahoo account it shows an error message:

> No OpenID endpoint found

It won't show the username and password fields; it directly shows the error message. How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you try entering your openID manually? If you do not know your id, log into yahoo and check under: Sign-In and Security > Manage/Create your OpenID.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for the hint. I couldn't log in either, but with your "workaround" I got in ;-)

Comment: I login my yahoo mail and search openId for yahoo and create http://openid.yahoo.com/ but still same problem, I open stackoverflow website then i click login and then i click yahoo then i get this error message `No OpenID endpoint found`

Comment: Hrm. This is a change on Yahoo's end... but it looks like it's here to stay. I'll take a look tomorrow to see what need to adjust anything on our end to better support it.

Comment: A better question; who still uses Yahoo? I thought that site died when Gmail came around killing Yahoo mail.

Comment: @Qix Lols :D some time need few more accounts so.

Comment: @AnnaLear hoo is it ? Thank you.

Comment: Back in with your yahoo account... I see you self answer between accounts: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617425/how-can-i-recreate-piechart-achartengine-on-spinner-item-click-in-android)

Comment: @Sri - Sorry, you misunderstood my suggestion :) You need to paste your *personalized* URL - not the general openid.yahoo.com URL. But it sounds like you eventually figured things out.

Comment: @Tanner Yeah it may useful to someone who facing problem like me, so i posted answer that its work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried it by manually pasting the open ID in `https://me.yahoo.com/(your username here)`

Basically, if your yahoo username is `funnykitty` (first thing that came to mind), then your open ID url that stack overflow is using is:

`https://me.yahoo.com/funnykitty`

It worked for me, I just tried it.

The problem is most likely because Yahoo has updated their services and somewhere along the line they broke the openID endpoint. It is most likely not StackOverflow's fault.

I highly suggest you add another alternate login; I used AOL because that's a good one to use. There's no guarantee this hack fix above will work forever, so better safe than sorry. Better than possibly losing access to your account forever.

---

**NOTE:**

Do NOT VISIT the url. Just put that URL into stack overflow at this location: 

   `Stack Overflow Login Page > 
   'More login options' > 
   Yahoo button > 
   BACK BUTTON (it will try to take you to the yahoo page) > 
   in the URL space below on this stack overflow page, paste the URL there`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time. I tried what you mentioned above, It take me to open `openid.yahoo.com` then I created login seal and come back and try to open my stackoverflow account still am getting same error

Comment: No do not VISIT the url. Just put that URL into stack overflow at this location: `Stack Overflow Login Page > 'More login options' > Yahoo button > BACK BUTTON (it will try to take you to the yahoo page) > in the URL space below on this stack overflow page, paste the URL there`

Comment: happy to help! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot am back with stackoverflow with my yahoo account.

Answer (score 8):

I have changed the default Yahoo! openId endpoint to `https://me.yahoo.com`, which fixes this issue.

With you in the next build (rev 2014.9.22.1881, meta rev 2014.9.22.2591).

Comment: I can't loging via yahoo either. I didn't know if I should create a new question or add an answer, so I made an answer here with error message

Comment: The yahoo endpoint is down again. `openid.yahoo.com` returns an error page.

Answer (score 7):

You could also try this.

When logging in using Yahoo,

1. On the Stack Overflow login page, click 'More login options'.
2. Click the Yahoo icon.
3. Paste `https://me.yahoo.com/<your username on Yahoo>`.

I just tried this today because I also can't login and I'm pretty sure its working. :)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer and time. That's working fine

Answer (score 1):

I cannot login using Yahoo open ID: here is the error message

The OpenID Provider issued an assertion for an Identifier whose discovery information did not match. Assertion endpoint info: ClaimedIdentifier: http://www.flickr.com/photos/*[myusername]* ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://www.flickr.com/photos/*[myusername]* ProviderEndpoint: https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth OpenID version: 2.0 Service Type URIs: Discovered endpoint info: [{ ClaimedIdentifier: https://www.flickr.com/photos/*[myusername]* ProviderLocalIdentifier: https://www.flickr.com/photos/*[myusername]* ProviderEndpoint: https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth OpenID version: 2.0 Service Type URIs: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon },]

Comment: Flickr might be doing something different (despite being owned by Yahoo). I *think* Flickr changed something recently and now requires you to use a different URL (it's somewhere in their docs... might be the URL you have in the address bar when looking at your Flickr profile while signed in?), but I can't verify it because I don't have a Flickr credential that pre-dates this. Please post a new question (tagged `bug`) and we'll try to get to the bottom of this.